# python Django как отобразить на странице содержимое json файла используя HttpResponse или иной метод

Tags: python, json, django, http

Есть обычный небольшой файл json:
Содержимое файла
cars.json:

[{"Name": "Honda", "Price": 10000, "Model": 2005, "Power": 1300},
{"Name": "Ford", "Price": 28000, "Model": 2009, "Power": 1200}]

Как возможно на (python, Django) отобразить на странице(сайт) отобразить содержмое файла cars.json используя например HttpResponse(или JsonResponse) ?

Примерно так вижу:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse            # для http
from django.http import JsonResponse            # для json
from django.core import serializers

def home(requests):
    return HttpResponse('Hello from Carl')    # данные в виде обычного str
    # return JsonResponse(cars.json)          # данные из файла json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). Из документации:

```
>>> from django.http import JsonResponse
>>> response = JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
>>> response.content
b'{"foo": "bar"}'
```

> Как возможно на (python, Django) отобразить на странице(сайт) отобразить содержмое файла cars.json используя например HttpResponse(или JsonResponse) ?

```
return JsonResponse({'foo': 'bar'})
```

В самой html, используйте интерполяцию `{{ foo }}`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/

Comment: интерполяция в html это пока для меня слишком :) уже страшно звучит... Спасибо за направление куда глядеть скажем так

Comment: Я бы сказал что это очень просто и удобно, посмотрите документацию - добавил в свой ответ.
Если ответ подходит - ставьте галку)